# Retrieve an existing VPC from Java program (AWS CDK)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need some help and I wonder if anyone can help here... I want to retrieve an existing VPC from Java program. I don't find many examples online and whatever I'm trying ends up nowhere.

So I was hoping maybe someone did that already.
Here is my code:

```
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.App;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Environment;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.StackProps;

public class MyFirstStackApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        App app = new App();

        new MyFirstStackStack(app,
                "MyFirstStackStack",
                StackProps.builder()
                        .env(Environment.builder()
                                .account("01234567891011")
                                .region("us-west-1")
                                .build()
                ).build()
        );

        app.synth();
    }
}
```

```
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Stack;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.StackProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.IVpc;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.Vpc;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.VpcLookupOptions;

public class MyFirstStackStack extends Stack {
    public MyFirstStackStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public MyFirstStackStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // The code that defines your stack goes here
        VpcLookupOptions vpcLookupOptions = VpcLookupOptions.builder()
                .vpcId("vpc-id-12345678")
                .isDefault(false)
                .build();
        IVpc myVPC = Vpc.fromLookup(this, "vpc-id-12345678", vpcLookupOptions);

        System.out.println("myVPC.getVpcId() = " + myVPC.getVpcId());
        System.out.println("myVPC.getVpcCidrBlock() = " + myVPC.getVpcCidrBlock());
    }
}
```

This always returns this:

```
myVPC.getVpcId() = vpc-12345
myVPC.getVpcCidrBlock() = 1.2.3.4/5
```

Which is of course completely incorrect. Any idea? Any suggestion?
Any help would be much appreciated

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that the VPC is not actually created by this CDK application and you're simply trying to retrieve details of an existing VPC created outside of CDK? If so, I don't think that's the purpose of CDK. You would use the regular [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) for that. CDK is not a general-purpose SDK for AWS resources. It has a specific role. You would use CDK to create infrastructure via CloudFormation templates.